How to resize layout with multiple EditText effectively on Android
I have the below layout and the default adjustPan doesn't seem to work well as user have to press back button to see remaining EditTexts

I tried switching to adjustResize for the windowSoftInputMode, but as shown below the result is unusable. I thought maybe wrapping the layout inside scrollview will help but nothing changed

Things I've tried include setting minHeight for the EditTexts but adjustResize doesn't respect that, I've tried the scrollview as said earlier too nothing changed
